# Size and other specifications of various buttons in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know whether apple have any specifications(size ,color) for using buttons(back button ,cancel button etc) in iphone..

Comment: YES FRIEND You can download the HIG pdf it shows all the specufication

Answer (score 1):

They do have a specification regarding the pixel size etc.. they have given the complete details inthe following document. Please go through [THIS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf)  link. It will clear all your doubts regarding the size and many more.
you can also have a look at [iPad HIG](http://www.hung-truong.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/iPadHIG.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

As HIG suggest it should be at least 44x44.